# Flashing text works in Firefox but not Chrome only with external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, external-js

One of the div headings (a text heading) on my home page is meant to fade in and fade out repeatedly to give a flashing effect, and the function is called onLoad of an image in my home.php file.

```
<h3 id="FlashingText" style="color:#fff;display:none;font-family:arial;font-     
weight:bold;font-size:16px">Text Flashes Here</h3>
//Lots of code
<img onLoad="FlashText()" etc. etc.>
//Lots of code
//Right before closing body tag
<script type="text/javascript">
function FlashText() {
$("#FlashingText").fadeIn(500).delay(500);
$("#FlashingText").fadeOut(500).delay(500);
FlashText();
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

When I place this script in the code for my home page (home.php) it works in all browsers. When I place this in an external js file (external js file is inserted right before closing body tag in the code above) it works in FF but not Chrome (I am using the latest versions of each). Interestingly, taking away the display:none in the h3 tag and changing the order of the fadeIn and fadeOut (i.e., putting fadeOut first) gives the same result.

Any ideas on why this might be happening? Worst case scenario I simply leave the script in home.php.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this anything like [the `<blink>` tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element#Usability_and_accessibility)?

Comment: I don't know...I have avoided <blink> (based on discussion about blink on this site) and have actually never used it

Comment: Have you tried this with jQuery's document.ready function?

Comment: No...I'll give this a shot...will let you know. Thanks!